# Swift 2 - switch statement giving me errors

Tags: swift, xcode7, swift2

I have no idea what is wrong, but the following code gives me a lot of errors in switch statement:

```
enum GameState {
    case Start
    case Tutorial
    case Play
    case ShowingScore
    case GameOver
}
```

in class GameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        switch GameState {
        case .Start: break
        case .Tutorial: break
        case .Play:
            beginningTouchPosition = location
            tappedForBird = true
            break
        case .ShowingScore: break
        case .GameOver: break
        }
    }

}
```

The error messages I get are:

1. Expected member name or constructor call after type name (this is in the switch GameState line)
2. Enum case "Start" not found in type "GameState" (I get this one not just for .Start, but for every GameState case)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to put a variable in the switch block and not a datatype?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used it like this before and it had worked..

Comment: You probably had a variable that had the same name as the datatype but in a different case (e.g. `gameState` as in instance of `GameState`)

Comment: You are right! I added 'var gameState = GameState.Start' at the beginning of the GameScene class, and it works now, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're switching on the enum type `GameState`.
You should switch on a variable containing one of the cases of `GameState`